# Legend keys overlapping when merging linetype and color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to merge the linetype and color legends to one but the keys are overlapping and cannot distinguish the colors

```
PLOT <- Plot %>% ggplot() + aes(x = Curvature, y = Moment, colour = Section, linetype = Section) +
 geom_line(size = 1) + scale_color_hue() + theme_classic() +
 labs(x = "Curvature (1/in)", y = "Moment (kip-ft)", color = element_blank()) +
 theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(),
   axis.title.y = element_text(size=20, colour="black", angle = 90, vjust = -3),
   axis.title.x = element_text(size=20, colour="black", vjust = 4),
   legend.position = c(0.78,0.2), axis.line.y = element_blank(), 
   axis.line.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
   axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), legend.text = element_text(size=20),
   legend.key.height = unit(1.0, 'cm'),legend.key.width=unit(3,"line"), 
   legend.title = element_blank()) + 
 scale_colour_manual(values = c("Bare Girder" = "black", "9' Spacing" = "dodgerblue",
                           "12' Spacing" = "hotpink", "15' Spacing" = "limegreen"), name="x") +
 scale_linetype_manual(values = c("Bare Girder" = "dashed", "9' Spacing" = "solid",
                           "12' Spacing" = "solid", "15' Spacing" = "solid"), name="x") +
 geom_segment(aes(x=0,y=0,xend=0,yend=80000), size = 0.7, colour = "black") + 
 geom_segment(aes(x=0,y=80000,xend=0.00028,yend=80000), size = 0.7, colour = "black") + 
 geom_segment(aes(x=0,y=0,xend=0.00028,yend=0), size = 0.7, colour = "black") + 
 geom_segment(aes(x=0.00028,y=0,xend=0.00028,yend=80000), size = 0.7, colour = "black")
```

The resulting plot is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are overriding the `color` in the legend via your `geom_segment`s when settinng `color="black"`. To prevent this you could add `inherit.aes=FALSE` to each of your `geom_segement`s or set the aesthetics inside `geom_line`.

BTW: You have two `scale_color_`s in your code so I dropped the `scale_color_hue`

Using `mtcars` as example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_line(aes(hp, mpg, color = factor(cyl), linetype = factor(cyl))) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "dodgerblue", "hotpink")) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=0,y=0,xend=0,yend=80000), size = 0.7, colour = "black") + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=0,y=80000,xend=0.00028,yend=80000), size = 0.7, colour = "black") + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=0,y=0,xend=0.00028,yend=0), size = 0.7, colour = "black") + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=0.00028,y=0,xend=0.00028,yend=80000), size = 0.7, colour = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: I see where the error is but I'm not sure how to resolve it. I tried adding inherit=FALSE to every geom_segment but I get the error "Ignoring unknown aesthetics: inherit"

Comment: Aw. Sorry. My fault. It's `inherit.aes=FALSE` and it's not an aesthetic but an argument, i.e. don't put it inside `aes()`